# FFmpeg (avconv) rtp stream, how to attach sdp file?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, avconv

I have a rtp live stream whit h.254 video, I want to copy it to file I use:

```
avconv -i rtp://@192.168.0.34:60005 -an -acodec copy -vcodec copy abc.mp4
```

But I have an error:

```
[rtp @ 0x1f6cfe0] Unable to receive RTP payload type 96 without an SDP file describing it
```

That's ok, because avconv don't know what is inside.

My sdp file:

```
v=0
o=- 20966096445 1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=x-qt-text-nam:brovotech
a=x-qt-text-inf:live/sub
a=range:npt=0-
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:8
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001e;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AHpWoLASZ,aO48gA==
```

How can I attach sdp file for FFmpeg? Or set some arguments that will describe the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use avconv -i camera.sdp

camera.sdp:

```
...
o=- 20966096445 1 IN IP4 my_ip
...
m=video my_port RTP/AVP 96
```